# autohotkey if var is with OR

Tags: variables, autohotkey, conditional-operator, operands

I know this is stupid simple, but it doesn't work.

Somehow I would like to shorten this variable using an operand but whatever . Can someone please show me a shorthand way writing this code?

```
var := "abc"
if (var = "abc" or var = "def" or var = "ghi")
{
    MsgBox Yes
}
else
    msgbox No
Return
```

IE: if var = ABC|DEF|GHI

also can I shorten the code to one line?

Comment: I just figured this works but still could be shortened

Comment: if regexmatch(var, "abc|def|ghi")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is functionally equivalent to your code in one line:**

```
msgbox % var ~= "^(abc|def|ghi)$" ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Comment: I was so close but missed the ~. Thanks!